# How can I get Session.SessionID from my MVC-Framework in unit tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mocking

For my unit-tests I use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and `MvcContrib.TestHelper`

my action in controller:

```
    public ActionResult index()
    {
        try
        {
            Session.Add("username", "Simon");
            var lSessionID = Session.SessionID;

            return Content(lSessionID);
        }
        catch 
        { 

        }

        return Content("false");
    }
```

my unit-test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexTestMethod1()
{

    TestControllerBuilder builder = new TestControllerBuilder();

    StartController controller = new StartController();

    builder.InitializeController(controller);

    var lResult = controller.index();

    var lReturn = ((System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult)(lResult)).Content; // returns "false"

    Assert.IsFalse(lReturn == "false");
}
```

When I call the `index()`-action in my browser, it shows the Session-ID. When I call the action via my unit-test, the `lReturn` is `"false"` and not the expected Session-ID.

How can I get the Session.SessionID in my unit-test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session variable is read from ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session , and Session is of the type HttpSessionStateBase.

with in the unit test, you can use set the ControllerContext object. ( or use any mock  providers like moq). **I have not tested the code**

```
var contextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
mockHttpContext.Setup(h => h.Session).Returns(session.Object);
contextMock.Setup(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(mockHttpContext.Object);
```

Comment: namespace HttpContextBase could not be found

Comment: you can add a reference to System.Web.dll

Comment: I have added Namespace System.Web. But Visual Studio also underlines HttpContextBase red with annotation: namespace HttpContextBase could not be found. I am using MVC3

Comment: Okay - HttpContextBase could be used now, but not "new HttpSessionStateBase()": Cannot create instance of abstract class or interface.

Comment: either you can create a TestSessionClass inherited from HttpSessionStateBase or create a Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> and setup the properties.